# Adding TIME data to a DATE type column in time series table, and what sort of foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, primary-key, datetime, date

I've got a v. simple table currently containing millions of data points of price on a given date:

```
CREATE TABLE data_point (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    symbol_id INT,
    x DATE,
    y DOUBLE
)
```

This is a timeseries database and for this release I'll keep data with a daily (or less frequent) period but if I need to add a time component, would it be better to change the `data_point` table and convert `x` to `DATETIME`?

If this did happen, initially all of the existing data would remain unchanged, it would not be adjusted - only future data (and not all of it) would be saved with time.

Or would it be better to add a second table with a one-to-one relationship to `data_point`, which held the time data?

Performance is more critical than space.

This leads on to the associated question about this table. Which is better in terms of performance for huge amounts of data, when all the queries on `data_point` will be joins from `symbol`? (Assuming `INT` for a primary key will get filled up within the app's expected lifetime)

```
CREATE TABLE symbol (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE data_point (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    symbol_id INT,
    x DATE,
    y DOUBLE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (symbol_id) 
        REFERENCES symbol(id)
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE data_point (
    symbol_id INT,
    x DATE,
    y DOUBLE,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (symbol_id, x),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (symbol_id) 
        REFERENCES symbol(id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, keep it simple - just use `DATETIME`.  I can think of two reasons to flake `TIME` off into another table, but neither are commonly applicable:

1. Your table is very large and in use constantly, so you can't afford to block it while changing a data type.  I'd still work around this by adding a new `DATETIME` column, populating it gradually, and then dropping the old `DATE` field when possible.
2. It's very important that you keep your table narrow, and you'll need the time values very rarely.

You've stated that performance is more important than space, but I really wonder if six bytes for `DATETIME2(0..2)` is really going to make much difference over three bytes for `DATE`.  You need to value your own time, and the time of everyone who tries to understand your system in the future.

Your question about the PK really should be asked separately.  However, I concur with Rick James that, in this case, you probably don't need a synthetic key (your `id` field); just index on `symbol_id` and `date`.  Assuming you're clustering on the PK, consider putting `date` first, so you can easily query date ranges.  If you primarily filter (not just join) by `symbol_id`, then put it first in the index instead.  If you do both, cluster on { `date`, `symbol_id` } and index on `symbol_id`.

Comment: I guess I could have made it two questions, but I figured the solution with two tables for date and time cols would impact the second question about primary and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

In my *experience* only 1/3 of tables need `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.  The other 2/3 have a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY`, such as your `(symbol_id, date)`.

The oft-quoted argument against natural PKs is their size.  But, unless you have *more than one* secondary key, that argument does not hold water.

I'm not a fan of `FOREIGN KEYs` -- they are a bunch of overhead for checking.  They imply that you can be lazy about writing 'correct code'.

I'm unclear on your questions about "time".  In general I recommend using a single column of type `DATETIME` instead of two columns - `DATE` and `TIME`.

What will the queries be?  One cannot really judge a schema, and especially its indexes, without knowing what the `SELECTs` look like.

Also, is the data coming in 'continually'?  (As opposed to bulk load nightly.)

Comment: The queries will be joining on symbol and sometimes also filtering on date. It will be coming in continually.

Comment: I like your contentious point about foreign keys and relational integrity = promoting laziness, if I understand you correctly - but don't foreign keys also speed up queries? Or does query performance rely solely on indexing?

Comment: Declaring a `FOREIGN KEY` implicitly creates an `INDEX` -- this is a performance boost.  But you can create that index manually (so I don't count it).  FKs _slow down_ insert/delete/update because the check the "constraint" imposed by the FK.